# ios Provisioning for Development - Invalid Private-Key/ Certificate Pair

Tags: iphone, provisioning, certificate, ios4

**See update below.**

This is driving me mad.  I have followed all the instructions and also deleted everything and restarted multiple times but I still keep getting the message above.

I am wondering whether part of the problem is that I have switched from my previous Individual Developer Programme to my new Company One.  I have read that I should use the Company Name in the Common Name field but that has not helped.  It still creates a certificate with my name, not the Company Name.

I can see that I have a private key against my certificate.

I have tried with the provisioning assistant and manually, but to no avail.

Any ideas warmly welcomed.

Chris.

**Update:**

@Bastian - thanks - this is just for Development on my new Company Developer Programme.  Once this is working, I'll then need to do similar for Ad hoc distribution. I have had both Development and Ad Hoc Distribution working on my personal Developer Programme working for some time.

I have deleted the certs and profile and followed your steps, but I still get the same error.

Within Keychain Access, under My Certificates, it looks like this...

> ....\/ [] iPhone Developer: Chris XXXX (xxxxxxxxx)........certificate
>   ........P Chris XXXX........................................................private key

and under Keys, it looks like this...

> ..........P Chris XXXX........public key
>   ....\/....P Chris XXXX........private key
>   ............[] iPhone Developer: Chris XXXX (xxxxxxxxx)........certificate

Comment: NB I am getting emails from Apple Developer saying the Certificate Request requires my approval but when I go in, there is nothing to approve. My understanding is that this has been done already by the assistant.  I am the only registered user of the Company Developer Programme,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was simply dragging the provisioning profile to the device within xCode organiser, not the library.  Simple once I realised.  Hopefully, this will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

the name you enter when creating the key is completely irrelevant. It's just for you to identify the key in your keychain.

What type of provisioning profile is you problem? development or distribution?

You should do in the following order:

- create a certificate request
- upload the request
  --- in a company account the team leader has now to confirm your request
- download the signed key

after that you should have a public/private key pair in your keychain which matches the one in the developer account.

now the team leader has to add you to the provisioning profiles of the apps in the account

after you have beed added you have to download the provisioning profiles from the developer site

now you should have a working key with working profiles.